# How to change default port 8080 in WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I just started JAVA EE development with WildFly 8.2. My first problem is how to change the default port 8080 to something else?

I found many xml files containing below line.

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
```

but I guess I don't have to change all of them?!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: But i am not we ;-). i just try to be polite - couldn't hurt at all. See the answer "Hope this helps!" - could also be omitted. But anyway - thanks for editing.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In your standalone.xml file, look for this element:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
```

The port-offset attribute lets you modify all the ports wildfly uses, by adding the number you specify.

For example, the default value is `0`, which means that http port will be `8080`, remoting `4447`, etc.

If you use `${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}`, http port will be `8180 (8080+100)`, remoting `4547 (4447+100)`, etc.

So you need to change the offset, nothing else.

EDIT: You can also do this by using a system property at startup, check http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/configuring-port-offset-on-jboss-as-wildfly

Comment: If you want to do this from command line something like this will work: start "wildfly" standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100

Answer (score 29):

An alternative would be to start the WildFly instance by directly specifying the port in the startup command.

---

Windows:

```
standalone.bat -Djboss.http.port=1234
```

*nix:

```
standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=1234
```

---

This would start the port for http-remoting on `1234`. Some context [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/configuring-port-offset-on-jboss-as-wildfly).

Comment: also -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 so you can change ALL ports (https, management etc)

Comment: Thx, this was what i was looking for. For testing i think the startup params are the best way :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to also offset your debug port if you are running in debug mode. This should be in the standalone.conf

Answer (score 4):

If you`re running on`Linux`, try this command at the start

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

If you`re working on`Windows` environment,

```
standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets:write-attribute(name=port-offset,value=100)
```

You may need to start the cli in offline mode if there is another wildfly running.