# Deploy application to wildfly on a certain port

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly

By default, applications in wildfly are deployed to `localhost:8080/app`. How to deploy application on dedicated port, i.e. open it on `localhost:8282` without application name ending?

I need to change the port for certain application, not the default port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default port 8080 in WildFly 8.2 release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922219/how-to-change-default-port-8080-in-wildfly-8-2-release)

Comment: Not, actually. That question is about changing default port and I'm asking how to change the port for the certain application only

Comment: I am not aware that it is possible, setting the port for only one app. I would suggest using a proxy for that purpose. With that, of course, you can also remove/change the application ending.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but AFAICT it should be possible to:

- run a single Wildfly instance listening on multiple HTTP ports. This is, in theory at least, possible (ref: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/233414?start=0&tstart=0)
- Configure undertow subsystem as a reverse proxy, and proxy your app to the other port/location (ref: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/configuring-a-reverse-proxy-with-undertow). That said, I have never used undertow for a reverse proxy and as such cannot speak for whether this really works.

Once you have done this, you have effectively just turned your Wildfly instance into an overly complex application server and reverse proxy in one. Ultimately however, the app in question would still be running on both ports, but you redirect the traffic using the proxy the way you would like.

The same proxy configuration in an Apache (ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse or https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/12/tutorial-apache-2-4-transparent-reverse-proxy/) or NGINX (ref: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/) would be IMHO less complex and better tested in countless production scenarios.