# How to run 2 (or more) Wildfly instances on the same machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, jboss-tools

I want to simulate 2 servers by running 2 independent instances of Wildfly. This is useful when you don't want to deploy all WARs on the same instance and then only be able to shut them down and start them together.

I'm using Eclipse with the JBoss plugin where in the Servers view I want to have 2 Wildfly servers that I can stop and run separately and simultaneously. How do I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible to duplicate your Wildfly installation folder, but that takes up more space and you would need to update both for every change. Instead it's possible to share the root folder and just create 2 standalones:

1. In the installation folder, create new `standalone1` and `standalone2` folders from the default (or use the default as one of them).
2. In there, in the `deployments` folder you can choose whichever deployments you need.
3. For the ports not to conflict, the `configuration/standalone.xml` of one of the standalones must be changed as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922906/3520484): change the number from 0 to something else like 200

   ```
   port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:200}
   ```
4. Now go to Eclipse and in the Servers view create a new Server. Give it some suitable name and click next.
5. Choose `create new runtime` on the bottom dropdown menu and click next.
6. Give it a suitable runtime name and in the `Server base directory`choose the standalone folder name you want, like `standalone1` above.
7. Then just deploy there whichever of the files you need for that particular instance.

Do the same for other instances with different offsets (in the above 1 instance will be at 8080 and the other at 8280).

Comment: I wonder, is this the best approach? I mean, for production enviroments. In case you have more thoughts on that I'd love read about it.

Comment: @vinyoliver I don't know if this is *best* for production. What alternatives are better?

Comment: I've ended up doing something pretty close to your answer for production. We have several apps each one running on its own instance of Wildfly and We also have a Nginx server working as reverse proxy. What I usually do is one app per server/instance but this project had this constraint that we had to use the same server for several apps

Comment: I may be losing something, but what sets the other instance to specifically 8280?

Answer (score 2):

after doing above Mark suggested method we have to run wildfly

in Windows

```
standalone.bat -Djboss.server.base.dir=D:/AppServer/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone1

standalone.bat -Djboss.server.base.dir=D:/AppServer/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone2
```

in Linux

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=/Users/kyle/servers/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone1

./standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=/Users/kyle/servers/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone2
```