# Run 2 Wildfly in the same Machine with different JBOSS_HOME

Tags: wildfly

I want to run 2 wildfly in the same Windows machine.
 The 2 wildfly must be in different versions.  The first one is wildfy 8 and the second in wilfly 14. 
I have set `JBOSS_HOME` for the first and `JBOSS_HOME1` for the second in the enviroment properties.
How to configure the second one the take `JBOSS_HOME1` properties

I have read 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697714/how-to-run-2-or-more-wildfly-instances-on-the-same-machine) but is a different problem.

I also have tried to put the `-Djboss.home.dir =<wildfly_base_path>` as argument  but it doesn't work

Comment: Is there an error message? Have you changed the ports on one of the instances?

Comment: No I don't have error message. I have set `port-offset`. The problem is that the second wildfly takes the `JBOSS_HOME` and not the `JBOSS_HOME1`.

Comment: Maybe something like `set JBOSS_HOME8=C:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final` and set a `JBOSS_HOME14` then just do `%JBOSS_HOME8%\bin\standalone.bat`.

Comment: where should I set that? In `standalone.conf.bat` ?

Comment: It's too late then. Where are they set now? How do you currently start the containers?

Comment: With commandline  I go to the specific path and I run `standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0`. I will check that you say and come back tomorrow because the servers are at my work.

Comment: Ah in that case you should just be able to do `whateverpath\bin\standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0` then. The `JBOSS_HOME` should be resolved from the path.